# Content Elements Ordering

Tags: stash, content-elements

I can’t seem to figure out how to do this correctly.

I’m using Content Elements as a field and stashing those values as you would typically do in a Stash list. However, when I call that list the sequence of what is being outputted seems to match the sequence in my code and not in the published entry.

Setting the list:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="h" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
  {h}

   {heading}
             {stash:h_header}{value}{/stash:h_header}
         {/heading}

   {wygwam}                     
       {stash:h_wygwam}{value}{/stash:h_wygwam}
   {/wygwam}

   {assets}                      
       {files}
        {stash:h_assets}{url}{/stash:h_assets}
        {stash:h_assets_alt}{alt_text}{/stash:h_assets_alt}
       {/files}
   {/assets}

  {/h}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

My template:

```
{if segment_1 == "about"}
 <div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
   {exp:stash:get_list name="h"}
    {count}
    {if h_header != ""}{h_header}{/if}
    {h_wygwam}
    {if h_assets != ""}<img src="{h_assets}"alt="{h_assets_alt}">{/if}
   {/exp:stash:get_list}
  </div>
 </div>

{/if}
```

Based on the above the {h_header} always gets listed first even though it might not actually be the first entry in the list. Hope this makes sense.

I have a feeling I’m not doing this correctly in Stash and not in Content Elements.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve this with the help from Mark Croxton.

Using a list target each content type with the same variable name. Example below:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="content-section-1" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}

  {c}

    {heading}
              {stash:content}{value}{/stash:content}
          {/heading}

    {wygwam}                     
        {stash:content}{value}{/stash:content}
    {/wygwam}

    {assets}                      
        {files}
         {stash:content}<img src="{url}" alt="{alt_text}" />{/stash:content}
        {/files}
    {/assets}

  {/c}

{/exp:stash:set_list}
```